# Rasterizing PDF vector objects - Acrobat

Tags: adobe-acrobat, rasterization

I need to rasterize vector objects in PDF files, possibly with Acrobat.
I need to rasterize only vector objects, not text.

I've tried separating PDF layers in multiple files, printing vector objects as images and then recombining the PDFs but the procedure is too complex, heavy and slow (sometimes I have to rasterize 1000 pages at once).

I've tried with the flattener preview. If I set the raster/vector slider to 0%, Acrobat rasterize all, also text, and I don't want it. Am I missing anything?

Is there any other procedure?

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *Fixup* in Acrobat that rasterizes everything besides text.

I don't know how familiar you are with *Preflight*. It's not my expertise, but I managed to find a way although the interface is quite quirky. I hope I'm not overlooking something, but test it and tell me how it goes.

- Open the *Preflight* window (it's in the *Print Production* tab in the right sidebar).

[image]

- Click the button in the top and *Create new Library* to have a library to put your custom fixups in.
- Click the wrench icon to switch to *Fixups*.
- Click the *Options* button and choose *Create Fixup*.

[image]

- Find *Convert page content into image* in the *Type of fixup* panel by using the search field.
- Most of the settings are self-explanatory when you know about images, so you can set them up as you like.
- To except text from being rasterized, find the *Except page objects* field, and click *Create new* (the plus icon).

[image]

- Find *Is text* in the *Property* panel by using the search field.
- Click the little *Add* button to the right.
- Set the property to *is true*.
- Click *OK* to save the *Check*.
- Click *OK* to save the *Fixup*.
- Run the fixup by double-clicking it or pressing the *Fix* button in the lower right corner.
- Choose a filename for the fixed file and press *Save*.

Comment: Thank you very much this procedure seems to work like a charme.
To be clearer:
- in the first step "Click the button in the top..." refers to the dropdown in the middle top

Comment: Can you tell what version of Acrobat you use? Can't find the "Except page objects" field on mine :(